# Tracking where a custom 404 is handled - code, IIS, etc?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

Is there any means to track where within code a `404` error is handled?

We have a site that we have taken over that doesn't seem to be reacting as expected.

We have changed the IIS custom errors page to point to the new page we would like but something seems to still be redirecting it to the old `404.htm` file in the root of this site.  We have not been able to track down where or why this happens.

Any suggestions on how we might find the referring logic?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application?

Comment: Yes ASP.NET DNN site.  I check the web.config and it has no custom error handling set there.  The IIS change worked fine on the test server which is a copy of prod website/code, however it is a clean IIS setup unlike production.  Seems if some other logic is getting in the way of the IIS redirect.

Comment: Did you check the global.asax page? Usually the URL re-writing is also done in global.asax file.